# Can anybody explain array declaration below with pointers

Tags: c

```
typedef short int(SPTR)[2];
SPTR *p, *q;
char a2D[5][3] =
 { { 1, 2, 3 }, 
 { 4, 5, 6 }, 
 { 7, 8, 9 },
 { 10, 11, 12 }, 
 { 13, 14, 15 } };
p = q = (short int(*)[2])a2D[1];
printf("%x %x\n",p,q);
printf("%x %x\n", (*++p)[1], (q[1])[2]);
printf("%x %x\n", p, q);
```

Can any body explain the arrays with pointers in above question,its an objective question.

Comment: Note that the parentheses in the `typedef` line are superfluous; the left parenthesis serves to separate `int` from `SPTR`, and its presence demands the right parenthesis, but using a space instead of the left parenthesis would be better.  … Or there's a `*` missing from inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef short int(SPTR)[2];
```

defines `SPTR` to be an array of two `short int`s.

```
SPTR *p, *q;
```

defines `p` and `q` to be pointers to arrays of two `short ints`. Without the `typedefs`, you could define them as:

```
short int (*p)[2];
short int (*q)[2];

p = q = (short int(*)[2])a2D[1];
```

This is an abuse of the explicit cast facility of the language.

Given the declaration of `a2D`, the type of `a2D[1]` is `char [3]`, i.e. an array of 3 `char`s. When used in an expression like above, it decays to a pointer, `char*`. Without the explicit cast, the assignments above would fail.

Everything else after that is difficult to make sense of. It comes under the category of undefined behavior.